# An assembler to assemble a hypothetical instruction set

Tags: c++, assembly

We have been given a college assignment (Yeah even during lockdown!!) to implement an assembler to assemble the reference instructions given [here](https://github.com/kesarling/SL-V/blob/master/assignment2/reference.txt). The following is my code to implement pass1 of the 
assembler. Please review it.

```
//imperative keywords
std::list<std::string> Mn_imp = { "READ","PRINT","MOVER","MOVEM","ADD","SUB","MULT","DIV" };

//declarative keywords
std::list<std::string> Mn_dcl = { "DS","DS" };

//assembler directives
std::list<std::string> Mn_drc = { "START","STOP","LTORG","EQU","ORIGIN" };

struct Row {
    std::string name;
    long LC_val;
    Row () { }
    Row(std::string _name, long LC) : name(_name), LC_val(LC) { }
    bool operator==(const Row& row) {
        return ((this->name == row.name) && (this->LC_val == row.LC_val));
    }
};

long LOCCTR = 0;

std::vector<Row> SYMTAB;
std::vector<Row> LITTAB;
std::vector<int> POOLTAB = { 0 };

std::string getToken(std::string& buffer) {
    std::string retToken;
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (i == buffer.size()) {
            buffer.clear();
            break;
        }
        else if (buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == ',') {
            i++;
            std::string newString(buffer.begin() + i, buffer.end());
            buffer.clear();
            buffer = newString;
            break;
        }
        retToken += buffer[i];
        i++;
    }
    return retToken;
}

bool getNumber(char* str, long* num_ptr) {
    bool flag = false;
    int i = 0;
    *num_ptr = 0;
    char ch = ' ';
    while (ch != '\0') {
        ch = *(str + i);
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            *num_ptr = (*num_ptr) * 10 + (long)(ch - 48);
            flag = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return flag;
}

short process_imp(std::vector<std::string> statement) {
    auto isRegister = [](const std::string& token) {
        return (token == "AREG" || token == "BREG" || token == "CREG" || token == "DREG");
    };

    //first argument
    if (!isRegister(statement[1])) {
        if (std::find(statement[1].begin(), statement[1].end(), '=') != statement[1].end()) {   //isLiteral
            if (std::find(LITTAB.begin() + POOLTAB.back(), LITTAB.end(), Row(statement[1], -1)) == LITTAB.end()) {   //check for presence
                LITTAB.push_back(Row(statement[1], -1));
            }
        }
        else if (statement[1][0] == 'F') {  //isNumber
            long number = 0;
            getNumber(const_cast<char*>(statement[1].c_str()), &number);
        }
        else {  //isVariable
            bool flag = true;
            for (const auto& row : SYMTAB) {
                if (row.name == statement[1]) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {
                SYMTAB.push_back(Row(statement[1], -1));
            }
        }
    }

    //second argument
    if (!isRegister(statement[2])) {
        if (std::find(statement[2].begin(), statement[2].end(), '=') != statement[2].end()) {   //isLiteral
            if (std::find(LITTAB.begin() + POOLTAB.back(), LITTAB.end(), Row(statement[2], -1)) == LITTAB.end()) {   //check for presence
                LITTAB.push_back(Row(statement[2], -1));
            }
        }
        else if (statement[2][0] == 'F') {  //isNumber
            long number = 0;
            getNumber(const_cast<char*>(statement[2].c_str()), &number);
        }
        else {  //isVariable
            for (auto& row : SYMTAB) {
                if (row.name == statement[2]) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            SYMTAB.push_back(Row(statement[2], -1));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

short process_drc(std::vector<std::string> statement) {
    if (statement.front() == std::string("START")) {
        if (statement.size() > 1) {
            getNumber(const_cast<char*>(statement[1].c_str()), &LOCCTR);
        }
    }
    else if (statement.front() == std::string("LTORG")) {
        int i;
        for (i = POOLTAB.back(); i < LITTAB.size(); i++) {
            if (LITTAB[i].LC_val == -1) {
                LITTAB[i].LC_val = LOCCTR++;
            }
        }
        POOLTAB.push_back(i);
    }
    else if (statement.front() == std::string("EQU")) {
        for (auto& row : SYMTAB) {
            if (row.name == statement[0]) {
                for (auto& _row : SYMTAB) {
                    if (_row.name == statement[2]) {
                        row.LC_val = _row.LC_val;
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (statement.front() == std::string("ORIGIN")) {
        //still to be implemented
    }
    else if (statement.front() == "STOP") {
        for (int i = POOLTAB.back(); i < LITTAB.size(); i++) {
            LITTAB[i].LC_val = LOCCTR++;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

short process_dcl(std::vector<std::string> statement) {
    for (auto& row : SYMTAB) {
        if (row.name == statement[0]) {
            row.LC_val = LOCCTR;
            if (std::find(statement[2].begin(), statement[2].end(), '=') != statement[2].end()) {   //isLiteral
                if (std::find(LITTAB.begin() + POOLTAB.back(), LITTAB.end(), Row(statement[2], -1)) == LITTAB.end()) {   //check for presence
                    LITTAB.push_back(Row(statement[2], -1));
                }
            }
            LOCCTR++;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    SYMTAB.push_back(Row(statement[0], LOCCTR++));
    if (std::find(statement[2].begin(), statement[2].end(), '=') != statement[2].end()) {   //isLiteral
        if (std::find(LITTAB.begin() + POOLTAB.back(), LITTAB.end(), Row(statement[2], -1)) == LITTAB.end()) {   //check for presence
            LITTAB.push_back(Row(statement[2], -1));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int process_line(std::string line) {
    auto find = [](std::list<std::string> list, std::string str) {      //could have used std::find()
        for (const auto& var : list) {
            if (std::string(var) == str) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    int retVal = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> token_vec;
    while (line != "") {
        token_vec.push_back(getToken(line));
    }
    //start processing the tokenised array
    auto token = token_vec.begin();
    std::string tok = token_vec.front();
    //pop the label
    if (tok[tok.size() - 1] == ':') {      
        SYMTAB.push_back(Row(tok, LOCCTR));
        token_vec.erase(token_vec.begin());
        tok = token_vec.front();
    }
    //find the type of statement
    unsigned short type = 0;
    if (std::find(Mn_imp.begin(), Mn_imp.end(), tok) != Mn_imp.end()) {
        type = 1;
    }
    else if (std::find(Mn_drc.begin(), Mn_drc.end(), tok) != Mn_drc.end()) {
        type = 2;
    }
    else {
        type = 3;
    }
    switch (type) {

    case 1: //imperative statement
        retVal = process_imp(token_vec);
        LOCCTR++;
        break;

    case 2: //assembler directive
        retVal = process_drc(token_vec);
        break;

    case 3: //declarative statement
        retVal = process_dcl(token_vec);
        break;

        //default: (not needed)

    }
    return retVal;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> code;
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(argv[1]);
    while (!infile.eof()) {
        std::string str;
        std::getline(infile, str);
        code.push_back(str);
    }
    infile.close();
    //Now we have the code in a string vector

    //check for a proper end
    if (code.back() != "STOP") {
        std::cerr << "Where do I stop?? Perhaps you forgot to put an end (STOP) statement?\n";
        return -1;
    }
    //if code is proper then begin pass1
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        auto line = code[i];
        short success = process_line(line);
        if (success == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Something wrong at line number " << i + 1 << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (success == 0) {
            //silence is golden :P
        }
        else if (success == 1) {

            for (const auto& i : SYMTAB) {
                std::cout << i.name << " " << i.LC_val << std::endl;
            }
            for (const auto& i : LITTAB) {
                std::cout << i.name << " " << i.LC_val << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. This is my first time implementing something this hard. Please bear with the code

Comment: Umm, will you please state what I am supposed to improve in the question?

Comment: I don't know who voted this down, I believe they also voted to close the question. The problem is that rather than following the line the information at the link should be here in the question, at least the opcodes should be and perhaps all of it.

Comment: Site standard is to have the title highlight what the code is to accomplish. I doubt the goal of assignment or coding is for the resulting assembler to be *lousy*.

Comment: (Did you try and follow [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @greybeard, thanks for the link and heads up. I will definitely work on my question asking skills :). And oh yeah, I didn't want the assembler to be lousy, I just thought it was 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Const initializers

In your constructor:

```
Row(std::string _name, long LC)
```

`_name` would be better-represented by a `const std::string &_name`.

Similarly,

```
process_imp(std::vector<std::string> statement)
```

should be

```
process_imp(const std::vector<std::string> &statement)
```

### `getNumber`

This has a C twang. C++ is able to do all of this for you.

First of all, if you wanted to keep it mostly as-is, do not use the ASCII code 48 directly; simply write `'0'`. That said,

- You should use something like `atoi`, though `atoi` itself does not support error detection, so this is ruled out. `atol` has similar issues.
- `sscanf` would work but is a C-ism.
- `istringstream` would do what you want.

### string comparison

```
statement.front() == std::string("LTORG")
```

does not need to construct a string on the right-hand side; simply compare the string literal, and the left-hand side's overloaded `==` will do the right thing.

### enums

```
//find the type of statement
unsigned short type = 0;
```

should be using an `enum` to capture the different possible types.